# How do we prove that $\int_0^1 (x\ln x)^{-1+n}\,dx = -\left( -\frac{1}{n} \right)^n \Gamma(n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, gamma-function

I need this solution to prove that

$$\int_0^1 (x\ln x)^{-1+n}\,dx = -\left( -\frac{1}{n} \right)^n \Gamma(n)$$

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Here is a [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so that you can typset this so iti s readable.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This is really hard to understand.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your questions.  Why is there $m$ on one side of the equation and $n$ on the other?

Answer (score 2):

First, let $t=\ln{x}$ and $dt=\frac{dx}{x}$ or $dx=e^t dt$:

$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{tn}t^{n-1} \; dt$.

You want the integral to be in the form of $\Gamma(x)=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t}t^{z-1} \; dt$, so let $u=-tn$ and $\frac{du}{-n}=dt$:

$\int_{\infty}^0 e^{-u} {\left(\frac{-t}{n}\right)}^{n-1} \frac{-du}{n}={\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}^n{\left(-1\right)}^n\int_0^{\infty} e^{-u} t^{n-1} \; du$.

Notice the integral is equal to $\Gamma(n)$, so the final answer is $\boxed{{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}^n{\left(-1\right)}^{n-1} \;\Gamma(n)}$